# How to customize simple Form text area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I want to customize input areas in  this code

```
<%= simple_form_for @fuel_price, url: supplier_fuel_prices_path, class: "m-t" do |f| %>
                                          <%= f.input :regular, label: "Regular" %>
                                          <%= f.input :medium, label: "Medium"%>
                                          <%= f.input :premium, label: "Premium" %>
                                          <%= f.input :diesel, label: "Diesel" %>
```

to have styling like the image below

[image]

I dont want horizontol or anything. Just want that dollor in front.

Or even better, something like below but with $ instead of @

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find solution [here](https://gist.github.com/chunlea/11125126/). He uses Bootstrap and SimpleForm

Comment: That was quite intense but got it all working following the directions in that link haha. Thank you.

Comment: please make annotation of resource you provide not only link itself

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **bootstrap** css library into your application and try the below code

```
simple_form_for @fuel_price, url: supplier_fuel_prices_path, class: "m-t" do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
    <%= f.text_field :regular, placeholder: "Regular", class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
   <%= f.text_field :medium, placeholder: "Medium", class:"form-control"%>

  </div
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
   <%= f.text_field :premium, placeholder: "Premium",class:"form-control" %>

  </div
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
   <%= f.text_field :diesel, placeholder: "Diesel",class:"form-control" %>   

  </div
 </div>
<%end%>
```